# Get HTTP error code in BizTalk when consuming rest

Tags: rest, biztalk, biztalk-2013

Using BizTalk 2013 I'm consuming a rest service with WCF-WebHttp adapter.

It is possible to capture the status code of failing requests and use this fault handling code?

[I've read this blog](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16625.biztalk-server-rest-services-error-handling.aspx). This describes a solution using wfc custom. I don't want to use this adapter because of all the nice features in the WCF-WebHttp adapter(Such as suppressing request body on verbs etc.

Comment: I'm using BTS 2013 R2 and have the same question.  How can I handle HTTP errors and get at the error code and message, without digging through SOAP-wrapped strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no solution.
Using a WCF-Custom and follow this blog http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16625.biztalk-server-rest-services-error-handling.aspx is the only solution I found.